# Android emulator access redir port from other host

Tags: android, emulation

Have a server-socket running in an android application, which I debug using the emulator. Using the emulators console and "redir add tcp:8888:8888" I can make the service available to a program running on my development machine (as localhost:8888).

The redir port is however not available on any other network interface, meaning I can't access it through the host-ip on either the local development machine, or from a secondary machine on the network. Anyone know if its possible to make the emulator bind to all network interfaces, or have some other trick to enable other hosts on the network to connect to the emulator?

Thanks

Comment: Found an ugly workaround by using http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/, but it really not ideal to have two extra network stacks that does buffering and forwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the emulator bounds socket on the local loopback. You can see it from the netstat command

```
$ netstat -an | more
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
...
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.8888         *.*                    LISTEN
...
```

"Local Address" should be *.8888 in order for your service to be reachable from outside.

The only solution you have is to forward a port from the physical interface to the local loop.

On linux, which is the system I understand you are using, the easiest way to do it is by means of iptables using any source interface as input and 127.0.0.1 as destination address.

You will need administrator privileges but it can be done on a per-session basis.

Comment: Can someone please explain how to do what Dario said above?  I'm having trouble figuring out the iptables command to do it.

> The only solution you have is to
> forward a port from the physical
> interface to the local loop.
> 
> On linux, which is the system I
> understand you are using, the easiest
> way to do it is by means of iptables
> using any source interface as input
> and 127.0.0.1 as destination address.

Thanks

(I would put this as a note under his answer, but I don't see how to do that..)

Answer (score 7):

I found the OP's comment/suggestion of using [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) to be much easier than iptables.

rinetd can intercept connections on one interface and forward them to a different IP; so, to solve this problem of the emulator not being accessible to computers other than the host machine, you intercept the incoming connections to your host and forward them to 127.0.0.1

Here's how:

First, install rinetd (http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/)

- Linux: either download it from the link above, or, in a terminal in Ubuntu, enter "`sudo apt-get install rinetd`".  The command could be different in other Linux distros...
- Windows: download from the link above (but it only says 95/98/NT..)

Next, set up a port redirection in the emulator:

- start your AVD
- in a terminal, enter "`telnet localhost 5554`" (or whatever the port for your avd is)
- once connected by telnet, enter "`redir add <protocol>:<host port>:<emu port>`" (e.g., "`redir add tcp:5000:7000`" to forward tcp data sent to port 5000 on the host to port 7000 in the emulator)

Configure rinetd:

- Edit the file `/etc/rinetd.conf` and add the line "`<host ip> <host port> 127.0.0.1 <localhost port>`". So if your host computer's IP address is 123.45.67.89 and you want to use port 5000 and then forward it to 127.0.0.1:5000, "`123.45.67.89 5000 127.0.0.1 5000`"

I'm not sure if rinetd is launched automatically after you install it.. to run it:

- "`/usr/sbin/rinetd`"

To re-initialize rinetd after modifying the config file:

- "`cat /var/run/rinetd.pid`" shows you the pid of rinetd
- "`sudo kill -1 <pid>`" re-initializes it (e.g, "`sudo kill -1 3225`")

Answer (score 1):

You can also use netcat for port forwarding.

Start the emulator then run the following using a terminal:

```
telnet localhost 5554
redir add tcp:<host port>:<emu port>
quit
```

Setup port forwarding:

```
nc -l -p <external port> -c "nc 127.0.0.1 <host port> -v" -v
```

If the `-c` switch is not available, you can use the following instead:

```
nc -l <external port> | nc 127.0.0.1 <host port> -v
```

As an example, if you want other computers to be able to connect to port 1234 of your android emulator, you will need 2 ports on your host computer.

- `<host port>`: port that listens on the local interface then forwards messages to port 1234. We will use 9200.
- `<external port>`: port that listens on any interface then forwards messages to the `<host port>`. We will use 9100.

Commands:

```
redir add tcp:9200:1234
nc -l -p 9100 -c "nc 127.0.0.1 9200 -v" -v
```

Comment: I wanted to connect to the telnet from other computer on the network, I used this tricked. Thanks it is very clean. `nc -l 5554 | nc 127.0.0.1 5554 -v`

Comment: does not work I get this error when I try to `redir add` -> `KO: unknown command, try 'help'`