# how to get emulator port number in program?

Tags: android, emulation

i want to get android emulator port number in program how do i get it????

Comment: Visit this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033046/android-emulator-access-redir-port-from-other-host

Answer (score 4):

Execute the command

```
netstat -aon
```

from command prompt. You will get all the PDIs and port numbers used by them. You can see the PID for emulator from **task manager** or use the command

```
tasklist
```

The process name is '**emulator-arm.exe**'

Answer (score 0):

By using the `netstat` command

Comment: Im developing Mobile banking app client and for this i want to recognize request is coming from which device for that im using post number as identity for demo purpose how do i get it???