# How to bridge/tuntap a network device from the Android emulator to the host

Tags: android, networking, emulation

Is there a way to bridge the network device of the Android emulator onto the host machine?

I have seen [these instructions](http://www.anddev.org/advanced_networking_with_android-linux-t155.html), but they are really old, the file names have changed, and my attempts to translate them to the current emulator haven't worked.  There are a few other similar examples around, but they're all from 2007-2008.  I must admit, my Linux- and especially networking-fu are not strong.  I could not get a second networking device (eth1) to show up in the emulator.

The reason I want to have the network device appear as a device on the host machine is that I need to be able to connect to the android device from a remote computer (not the host), through rsh (which I've been able to do, as shown in my [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033046/android-emulator-access-redir-port-from-other-host)), and then use ssh from within to connect to another remote computer.  I can get in to rsh, but I can not ssh out (or ping the remote computer).  (I've been provided with an image with rshd on it, and this works fine on an actual phone, but the emulator's network devices being hidden is causing problems)

If an eth1 could be created and bridged, that would be great.  I'm also open to bridging eth0 (but I'd want to change the IP to 172.x.x.x to be on the same subnet as the remote computers)

Thanks.  I'll try to clarify anything if you ask.

Answer (score 2):

1) Download the LiveAndroid iso from the [LiveAndroid Project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/wiki/howtouse). Or alternatively, download Android-x86 iso from [here](http://www.android-x86.org/download). 2) Boot it as a virtual machine with VMWare or VirtualBox. 3) Configure your virtual machine to use Bridge networking, as you would per any regular virtual machine. 4) Install Android SDK the other tools like `adb` onto your Host computer. Connect using `adb` to the virtual machine as if it were a real android hardware device.

Note: LiveAndroid is an EE-PC based virtual machine. It thinks its running on EE-PC hardware. So there will be no QEMU-based android emulator running. The network bridging will be performed by the Host-OS drivers provided by your chosen virtualization software.

Comment: This sounds like it would work, except that I need the most up-to-date version of Android and the LiveAndroid project does not appear to have been updated since 2009.

Comment: well this method is no longer valid. anyone knows how this can be done in Android 10 environment?