# socket from android emulator (client) to host machne(server)

Tags: android, sockets, emulation

I tried to send some message from android emulator to host machine using socket. 
On the host machine (ubuntu), android emulator which is socket client is running. 
The host is listening with specific port number (i.e. 9090) and 
the client sends messages when you open a specific html page, which embeds javascript code to send message through ip address and port number.

For this, I tested this methods with other machine or in the host machine. 
When I open the html page in other machines or host machine to send messages (client side), 
the host (ubuntu) gets them (no need to respond to client: it's like POST). 
However, Using the android emulator web browser, when I open the page, there's no message received in the server side. 
I guess the problem is port available/open in the emulator side.

Is there a way to open or create port number in the emulator side to send messages to Host machine? 
Or is there a sort of internal ip address between host machine and emulator..? 
I'm stuck with this.. 
Anyone can help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033046/android-emulator-access-redir-port-from-other-host?rq=1

Comment: @PabloLozano - that actually seems to be a different issue.

Comment: At what address have you tried to contact the service running on the host?  You should probably use the special host loopback alias address, 10.0.2.2, but be aware that this will *only work from an emulator* and not on a real device.

Comment: Let's say the host machine ip address, 129.128.19.1. (from ifconfig). So, I used this ip address for the html page in emulator browser (client side). How do I use host loopback alias address? and what port number? Actually, if I use one of the port numbers for socket server after checking ips and ports using "netstat" on adb shell, the socket server in the host is not working due to "BindException: Address already in use". I don't know about network connection or emulator much.. :( could you rephrase a little bit more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution is :
Just use gateway to send some message to Host machine. 
In my case, 10.0.2.2:9090 works.